# Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, tinymce-4

I have following code in my laravel app and tinymce won't load instead I get this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: tinymce is not defined

## Code

```
<textarea class="form-control editor" name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="10">

</textarea>

////

<script src="{{asset('js/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js')}}"></script>


<script>
$(function(){
  var editor_config = {
    path_absolute : "/",
    selector: "textarea.editor",
    plugins: [
      "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
      "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
      "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
      "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern codesample",
      "toc tinymcespellchecker imagetools help"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | fontselect |  fontsizeselect | bold italic strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | ltr rtl | bullist numlist outdent indent removeformat formatselect| link image media | emoticons charmap | code codesample | forecolor backcolor",
    external_plugins: { "nanospell": "https://www.xxxxx.com/js/tinymce/plugins/nanospell/plugin.js" },
    nanospell_server:"php",
    browser_spellcheck: true,
    relative_urls: true,
    remove_script_host: false,
    branding: false,
    file_browser_callback : function(field_name, url, type, win) {
      var x = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;
      var y = window.innerHeight|| document.documentElement.clientHeight|| document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientHeight;

      var cmsURL = editor_config.path_absolute + 'laravel-filemanager?field_name=' + field_name;
      if (type == 'image') {
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Images";
      } else {
        cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=Files";
      }

      tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
        file: '<?= route('elfinder.tinymce4') ?>',// use an absolute path!
        title: 'XYZfile manager',
        width: 900,
        height: 450,
        resizable: 'yes'
      }, {
        setUrl: function (url) {
          win.document.getElementById(field_name).value = url;
        }
      });
    }
  };

  tinymce.init(editor_config);
 });
</script>

<script>
  {!! \File::get(base_path('vendor/barryvdh/laravel-elfinder/resources/assets/js/standalonepopup.js')) !!}
</script>
```

> Error refers to this line at **HTMLDocument.  (create:1613)** -> `tinymce.init(editor_config);`

**Any idea?**

Comment: Probably because you are inserting it directly in your blade template. I guess tinymce requires jquery to work and is not loaded yet because it is in footer? Make sure, jquery is loading before of that

Comment: well i have general jquery in my layout which will place above this code and then i have 2 js files in this blade as i shared in my code `jquery.tinymce.min.js` and `tinymce.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE does not require jQuery to run.  That specific error implies that the core TinyMCE JavaScript file was not loaded as that file is what creates the global `tinymce` object.

If the global `tinymce` object is not there you can't call `init()` on a non-existent object hence the specific error.

Look in the Network tab of your dev tools to see what is happening when you try to load the `tinymce.min.js`  file.  I suspect you will find it is not loading and if you fix that this error will stop.